# IIS Page buffering SLOW things down

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, buffer

I have an MVC 5 web application. I have two different pages which have pretty heavy table generation. By default, the response buffering is ON, and both pages are significantly slower to render when buffering is ON.

If I add

Response.Buffer=false

in the action result, turning buffering off, the page load is much faster.

The difference is 5 seconds with buffering ON vs 1 second with buffering OFF.

What's could the explanation be for this? I always thought buffering would speed things up, not slow them down.

Comment: As far as I know, Response.Buffer=false is suitable for classic asp, and your project is mvc,  if you want to set  buffer output and send it after the complete page is finished processing, you can try to use `Response.BufferOutput()`.

Comment: By default, the response is buffered to in MVC/IIS. I'm overriding that. It's a perfectly valid option in MVC.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, did you solve your problem?

Comment: I mean that this doesn't have anything to do with Classic ASP, and Response.Buffer is a perfectly valid property setting in MVC/C#.

The way the app is currently set up, buffering is ON by default. This the case of this page and another, the page is rendered much faster when buffering is off.

Comment: I know that Response.Buffer can be encoded in mvc, but it is indeed an attribute in asp, you can refer to this link: [Response.Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms526001(v=vs.90)), and normally we use Response.BufferOutput() in MVC, so I suggest you use Response.BufferOutput() to see if you will encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I don't think you understand what has been written. IIS is already configured to buffer the output. It's slower with buffering on than off.

Comment: How do you configure buffer output in iis? As far as I know, only asp components can configure buffering in IIS.

Comment: For classic ASP it's in the IIS/ASP section "Enable Buffering". Default is set to True.
For .net it's on by default, and you can override it with the Response.Buffer property in the controller.

Comment: Have you tried using Response.BufferOutput = true? Do you encounter the same problem if you try? Can you share me your code?

Comment: By default, Response.BufferOutput is equal to true, and that's when the page loads slowly.